# AngularJS form.validation is not a Function

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope, angularjs-http

AddClass.cshtml File has the form and ng-validate uses the validation option. When I click the Add Class button in cshtml file without entering any value in Textboxes, it should show error messages but i get form.validation() is not a function error. All the js files are already present such as angular-validate.min and jquery.validate.min. Any idea what might be the problem??

```
<form name="addclassform" id="addclassform" ng-submit="addClassForm(addclassform)" ng-validate="classValidationOptions">
    <div class="modal-body">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="ClassName" class="col-md-3">Class Name</label>
            <input name="ClassName" id="ClassName" class="form-control" ng-model="addClassFormData.ClassName" />
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="Location" class="col-md-3">Location</label>
            <input name="Location" id="Location" class="form-control" ng-model="addClassFormData.Location" />
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="TeacherName" class="col-md-3">Teacher Name</label>
            <input name="TeacherName" id="TeacherName" class="form-control" ng-model="addClassFormData.TeacherName" />
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Add Class</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

This is the AngularJS file. The classValidationOptions has all the rules and form.validation() throws an Error in $scope.addClassForm

```
//Validate Class
$scope.classValidationOptions = {
    rules: {
        ClassName: { required: true },
        Location: { required: true },
        TeacherName: { required: true }
    },
    messages: {
        ClassName: { required: "Please enter Class Name." },
        Location: { required: "Please enter the Location." },
        TeacherName: { required: "The field is required." }
    }
};

$scope.addClassFormData = {};

//Adds a Class
$scope.addClassForm = function (form) {
    if (form.validate()) {
        $http({
            method: "POST",
            url: "/Home/AddClass",
            data: $.param($scope.addClassFormData),
            headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' }
        }).then(function Success(response) {
            var data = angular.fromJson(response.data);
            if (data.success) {
                $scope.loadClasses();
                $('#addClass').modal('hide');
                $scope.resetClassForm("add");
                //toastr.success(data.msg, 'Success');
            }
            else {
                //toastr.error(data.msg, 'Error');
            }
        });
    }
};
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9A4zo.png)

Answer (score 0):

I found the Error. The problem was I was not writing `ngValidate` in the module

Incorrect Code

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
```

Correct Code

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', ['ngValidate']);
```